# Snapped rotation with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, rounding

I'm trying to get a 3D object to look at another object, but only in increments of 90 degrees. I achieved this by dividing the eulerangles by 90, rounding them, then multiplying them by 90 again. This worked out pretty well.

Or at least it DID, except now I want these 90 degree increments to also rotate based on the rotation of another object. The problem is, I can't figure out the proper way to add an offset to this rotation.

One method I tried was, for each axis of my eulerangle rotation, I would add the rotation axis of that other object I mentioned, and then subtract it again after rounding the rotation to the nearest 90th degree. However, this not only provides me with the wrong rotations, but also gives me 8 possible final rotations instead of just 6.

I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to fix it. What am I missing?

```
extrudeTransform.LookAt(transform.position);

//extrude with modified rotation when extruding off surface

//set euler vector with initial rotations for base transform that points at the cursor

Vector3 tempExtrudeRot = new Vector3(extrudeTransform.eulerAngles.x, extrudeTransform.eulerAngles.y, extrudeTransform.eulerAngles.z);

Vector3 originRotAdjustmentVar = new Vector3(extrudingOffObject.transform.eulerAngles.x, extrudingOffObject.transform.eulerAngles.y, extrudingOffObject.transform.eulerAngles.z);

//temporarily adjust vector based on rotation of base object

tempExtrudeRot = tempExtrudeRot + new Vector3(originRotAdjustmentVar.x, originRotAdjustmentVar.y, originRotAdjustmentVar.z);

//round to the nearest 90th degree

tempExtrudeRot = new Vector3((Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.x / 90f))*90f, (Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.y / 90f)) * 90f, (Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.z / 90f)) * 90f);
                
//remove vector adjustment from base object
                
tempExtrudeRot = tempExtrudeRot - new Vector3(originRotAdjustmentVar.x, originRotAdjustmentVar.y, originRotAdjustmentVar.z);
                
//finalized rotation
                
extrudeTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(tempExtrudeRot);
```

Comment: just to see i I understood correctly - you want to rotate in `90°` increments - but you want some initial offset so the rotation should not snap to absolute `90°` values but rather `offset + (x * 90°)`? It is a bit hard to see which of your given variables provides which values

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want a rotation offset. In my posted code, the rotation I want to adjust by is named originRotAdjustmentVar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is have an initial `offset` rotation thus that your final rotation basically is

```
offset + n * 90°
```

so not sure but I think you would go the other way round

- first subtract the `offset`
- then calculate `n` in order to snap to 90°
- then re-add the `offset` for the final result

So something like e.g.

```
var tempRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - extrudeTransform);
var tempExtrudeRot = tempRot.eulerAngles;
var originRotAdjustmentVar = extrudingOffObject.transform.eulerAngles;

// remove offset
tempExtrudeRot -= originRotAdjustmentVar;

//round to the nearest 90th degree
tempExtrudeRot.x = Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.x / 90f)) * 90f;
tempExtrudeRot.y = Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.y / 90f)) * 90f;
tempExtrudeRot.z = Mathf.Round(tempExtrudeRot.z / 90f)) * 90f;
                
//remove vector adjustment from base object
tempExtrudeRot += originRotAdjustmentVar;
                
//finalized rotation
extrudeTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(tempExtrudeRot);
```

in other words for the snapping you first want to rotate (virtually) into a non-rotate reference space (thus removing the offset initially).
Then while you are in this "neutral" orientation space you do your snapping (so basically snapping relative to this offset). And then you apply the offset back to the already snapped rotation to convert i back into the rotated world space

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately that did not solve the problem. However, some of your variable references are much more concise, and that will make this more readable at least.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution!
After spending like a week on this, I couldn't figure out how to get the math to work at all. However, I figured out that if I take my extrudeTransform object, and make it a child of a new extrudeTransformGimbal object, I can rotate the parent object before getting my tempExtrudeRot variables, and then I can calculate tempExtrudeRot based on local rotations instead of global rotations.

Then, I can do away with the originRotAdjustmentVar calculations altogether, do the rounding calculations, and set the extrudeTransform local rotation instead of its global rotation.

That gave me what I'm looking for!